# Linear Algebra and planes in Cartesian space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was asked this question from the course Linear Algebra and I need to show all working.

The question is in 5 parts:

Consider the *xyz*-space R<sup>3</sup> with the origin *O*. Let *l* be the line given by the Cartesian equation $$x = \frac{z - 1}2, y = 1 $$ Let *p* be the plane given by the Cartesian equation $$2 x + y - z = 1$$

a) Find two unit vectors parallel to the line *l*.

b) Find the point *Q* which is the intersection of the plane *p* and *z*-axis.

c) Take **n** = 2 **i** + **j** - **k** as a normal vector of the plane *p*. Decompose the vector *QO* into the sum of two vectors: one of them is parallel to **n** and the other one is orthogonal to **n**.

d) The plane *p* divides R<sup>3</sup> into two parts. Find the unit vector perpendicular to *p* and pointing into the part containing the origin *O*.

e) Let *P*(*x*, *y*, *z*) be a point on the line *l*. Letting *x* = *t* for some constant *t*, find the *y* and *z* coordinates of *P*. Calculate the distance from *P* to the plane *p*.

I would like to thank everyone who takes time in helping me with this problem and I really appreciate the help.

Thanks again.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where are you facing difficulties?

Comment: I found b) as Q(0,0,-1) by subbing in x,y=0. Then I did c) using the vector projection and dot products. I got the answers parallel: -1/6*(2i+j-k); orthogonal 1/6*(2i+j+5k). For a) I manged to get out the answer +/-1/root(2)*(j+k) (+/- because they point at opposite directions. Not sure if right or not). I'm just not sure how to go about d). What are the two parts? For e) I subbed in x=t into the line equation and got the point P=(t,1,2t+1). I used P with Q(0,1,0), which is a point on the plane (got by inspection). I got the distance 1/root(6). Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: for c) how did you get the 1/6 part. I can get the vectors but where did the 1/6 come from. is it sqrt(2^2+1^2+1^2+2^2+1^2+5^2)? but what's the reason for that

Answer (score 0):

for part d), i'm not 100% sure but couldn't we say that it will either be the normal vector n, or the one in the opposite direction -n?
and then use the formula for a distance (d) from a point P (the origin) to a plane containing Q (found from part a) with normal vector (n) as d = |n.PQ|/|n|, but then take away the absolute values from the top part of the fraction to give us a "direction" to the distance between the plane and the origin and thus the unit vector will be the one with the same sign as that direction?
like i said this could be total rubbish, but just a thought! :)

Answer (score 0):

***Here is my solutions. FYI I can do only half d).*** Will maybe continue working on it someday later. Hope it helps.

a) use parametric form of 3D-line, and the coefficients of the parameter 't' will be your direction vector: i + 2k. Then simply work out it's +/-ve two unit vectors by dividing its modulus: sqrt(1^2 + 2^2), and eventually I got: **+-(i + 2K)/sqrt5**

b) **same.**

c) **same.**

d) However you don't know what the two parts are, you should be able to find the unit vector perpendicular/normal/orthogonal to a plane. I don't know how to show which vector is pointing into where the origin is, but I can show you from which two you can choose, i.e. the unit vectors pair:

The normal vector to a plane is simply of the coefficients of the plane equation. In this case, our plane is given: 2x + y - z = 1 (Don't worry about the 1 at last, it can be any constant), → normal vectors pair: +-(2, 1, -1), or say: n = +-(2i + j - k).

Therefore the unit vector of n: n_hat = n/|n| = +-(2i + j - k)/sqrt(2^2 + 1^2 + (-1)^2)
I.e. the unit vectors pair **n_hat = +-(2i + j - k)/sqrt6**

Then you may wish to find someone else to teach you which one is pointing in where the origin part is, either the +ve n_hat or the -ve.

e) I use your P and Q, which I agree with you:
QP.n = (t, 0, 2t+1).(2, 1, -1) = -1
where |n| = sqrt6
therefore distance d = |QP.n|/|n| = **1/sqrt6**

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: @enya. I don't understand how you even got 3a.

Comment: Imagine that you are standing at point (0,0,0). Then, as 2*0+1*0-0*0=0<1, the origin O is under the plane. This means you have to look upside to see the plane. Thus, sign the vector \hat{k} should be -. Therefore, (2i+j-k)/sqrt(6) is the vector contained in origin part.